# VLCKit Unable to play video in cocoa programming for objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I had tried to play video using vlckit for mac os x,
using below code but , i am unable to see video, after compiling i am having black screen but no video is playing.

here a.mp4 is my video inside main bundle , i had cheacked that videos path is correct. 
let me know what is the issue why i am not able to see video on screen.

```
// Set up a videoView by hand. You can also do that in the nib file
videoView = [[VLCVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
[videoView setAutoresizingMask: NSViewHeightSizable|NSViewWidthSizable];

// Init the player object
player = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithVideoView:videoView];
[player setMedia:[VLCMedia mediaWithPath:@"/Users/gurpalrajput/Desktop/demoVlc Player/demoVlc Player/a.mp4"]];
    [player play];
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to set an arbitary file path to a class.  That's basics for macOS software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path looks wrong; for a resource inside a *macOS* application I would expect something like `/path/to/Application.app/Contents/Resources/a.mp4`. You're not on iOS anymore... ;)

Generally you want to resolve paths to resources inside the application bundle programmatically; for the movie that would be:
`NSString* path = [NSBundle.mainBundle pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"mp4"];`